# start 1 view controller 2 buttons that lead to 2 different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the first ViewController that has 2 buttons on it. One to go to ViewController1 when clicked and the other to go to ViewController2 when clicked. When i click the first button it takes me to ViewController1 but when i click the second button it goes to a black screen and gives the warning:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!

What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)goToYourClosetViewController: (id)sender{
    YourClosetViewController *closet = [[YourClosetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:closet animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(IBAction)goToPlanOutfitViewController: (id)sender{
    PlanOutfitViewController *planOutfit = [[PlanOutfitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:planOutfit animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: have you try using `[[YourClosetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourClosetViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];` ?

Comment: Do you mean you have total of 3 view controllers?

Comment: yeah i have a total of 3 view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Are you pressing the first button and then the second button in rapid succession by any chance?

If that's it then you need to disable your buttons while the modal presentation is in progress, and re-enable them in your completion blocks.

If not, then how are you displaying the first view controller? (The one that contains these 2 buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying open the second view controller before you close the first view controller. That's the kind of error message in such cases.

When you go back to your initial view controller from either first or second view controller, do this:

```
[FirstViewControllerInstance dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```